# Getting invalid month names in DateTime formatting

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a simple program which will return the Day and the ShortDate. For example, if the input is 27th March 2016, the output will be "Sun, 03/27/2016"

```
string ShortMonthFormat = "ddd";
DateTime dtc = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-03-27 12:26:41.210");
string result = dtc.ToString(string.Format("{0}, {1}", ShortMonthFormat, dtc.ToShortDateString()));
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This code works for the current system Date format which is `MM/dd/yyyy`(03/27/2016). But if the system's Date format is changed to `dd-MMM-yy`(27-Mar-16), the code is returning the following output `"Sun, 27-3ar-16"`

Mar(March) is returned as `"3ar"`

Aug(August) becomes `"AuA.D."`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`M` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#M_Specifier) meaning is single digit month number from `1` to `12` and [`g` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#gSpecifier) means period or era such as `A.D.`

Since other characters doesn't referring *any* format specifiers, they reflected to the output *exactly* what they are.

By the way, your code seems little bit complicated and buggy. First, you generate a format with using `ShortMonthFormat` and `ToShortDateString` and then generate string representation of your `DateTime` with *that* formatted string.

That's why your code looks like;

```
string result = dtc.ToString("ddd, 27-Mar-16");
```

which does not *too* much sense.

You can fix your code to use your [`ShortDatePattern` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern) of your `CurrentCulture` instead of you use `dtc.ToShortDateString()` like;

```
string result = dtc.ToString(string.Format("{0}, {1}", 
                             ShortMonthFormat, 
                             CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern));
```

By the way, based on variable name (which is `ShortMonthFormat`), [`ddd` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dddSpecifier) is for abbreviated day names. If you wanna get abbreviated month names, you can use [`MMM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MMM_Specifier) instead.

```
string ShortMonthFormat = "MMM";
```

Comment: What the code I think does is     string result = dtc.ToString(ddd,"27-Mar-16"); Is formatting like this wrong?

Comment: @user1890098 Updated. Take a look.

Comment: Actually I need the day name and not the month name. Poor variable name on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a bug in your code. You are trying to get the short date format but instead of getting the format you format the date which will result in a formatted date and not the format. You can fix this in your code:

```
string format = string.Format(
  "{0}, {1}",
  ShortMonthFormat,
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
);
string result = dtc.ToString(format);
```

You have not specified a `CultureInfo` so `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is used which is reflected in `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`. If you want to use another `CultureInfo` you will also have to use it in `dtc.ToString(format, cultureInfo)`.

Another way to explain the fix is that you have to replace `dtc.ToShortDateString()` with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Martin